# Update the "Recommended" Default Apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, default-settings, windows-server-2019

How do I update the *Microsoft Recommended defaults* in **Settings, Default apps**?  In other words, I want to change which *Web browser* would be selected, if I click the **Reset** button.

**Background:**

I have a Windows Server 2019 which somehow still defaults to Internet Explorer.  When new users log in, they still get Internet Explorer as a default then complain that pages do not load correctly.  The server is up to date with all Microsoft Updates.

I tried setting the group policy DefaultAppAssociations, but this forces the default browser for all users.  I only want to set the "initial" default browser if the user has not already selected a browser.

[image]

Comment: Your describe situation, shouldn't be possible, if the Windows Server 2019 installation has received all Microsoft Edge updates.  Microsoft Edge rather than a Windows Update remove Internet Explorer. You can force the behavior by implementing the group policy as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/set-the-default-browser-using-group-policy)

Comment: @Ramhound, I tried to force the behavior, but it forces the default browser for all users, even if they selected their own.

Comment: Ok; But did you disable Internet Explorer through the group policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting the group policy DefaultAppAssociations, but this forces the default browser for all users. I only want to set the "initial" default browser if the user has not already selected a browser.

The Microsoft Edge update released in February 2023, if it was installed, should have removed the ability for users to launch Internet Explorer.  The initial default browser today, should be Microsoft Edge but based on the described behavior it does not sound like Microsoft Edge has been updated since before the applicable February 2023 update.

> I have a Windows Server 2019 which somehow still defaults to Internet Explorer.

If you have updated Microsoft Edge since February 14, 2023, this shouldn't be possible, but it apparently is possible, so you can simply disable Internet Explorer through a group policy.  This would allow your users to select a different browser, but would allow you, to prevent Internet Explorer from being used.

> - You would need to first install the Windows 10 Admin ADMX group policy template which can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=103124&msclkid=eae4a72fb1fb11ecb97ca3096b36cc06).
> - Open the Group Policy Editor
> - Go to **Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer**
> - Double-click **Disable Internet Explorer 11** as a standalone browser and Select Enabled.
> - Under Options, pick one of the following values:
>
>   - Never if you don’t want to notify users that IE11 is disabled.
>   - Always if you want to notify users every time they're redirected from IE11.
>   - Once per user if you want to notify users only the first time they are redirected.
> - Select **OK** or **Apply** to save this policy setting.

Source:

- [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549)
- [Disable Internet Explorer 11 as a standalone browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-disable-ie11#disable-internet-explorer-11-as-a-standalone-browser)

> In other words, I want to change which Web browser would be selected, if I click the Reset button.

This would simply override the user's selected default browser and reset it to the default browser.  Since Internet Explorer is NOT disabled on the system, and Internet Explorer when it was NOT disabled, was the default browser.  **You would simply be setting the default browser back to Internet Explorer.**

Comment: At one time I had an answer that figured out, which update in February 2023, remove Internet Explorer.  I can't seem to find that answer, or perhaps it was a comment, I honestly don't recall and have time constraints that will prevent me from looking for it further.